# Can't see the layout phone in android studio

Tags: android, layout, android-studio

I am working in a new app and after I created 
I went to android layout and I found nothing I can't see the device 
that I will working on it and I couldn't see the screen or the API in the app

http://im62.gulfup.com/0tkqZs.png

Comment: did you try go to xml and add some views? switching between xml & layout often helps.

Comment: @MargaritaLitkevych yes i did but nothing change in xml design and thank you